# How does the Terminal and the Shell exchange data?

Tags: shell, terminal, tty, terminal-emulator, pty

In Linux, a Terminal is associated with a Shell. The Terminal send input to the Shell (for example: `pwd`), and the Shell send the output back to the Terminal (for example: `/home/paul`).

This diagram shows the relationship between a Terminal and a Shell (assume that the Terminal I am using is `gnome-terminal`, and the Shell is `bash`):

[image]

Now what I want to know is what mechanism does the Terminal and the Shell use to exchange data. This is what I think happens:

- When `gnome-terminal` is executed, it will create a file representing a
  serial port in the `/dev/pts` directory (let's say the file name is `/dev/pts/0`).
- `gnome-terminal` will then execute the Shell associated with it (for
  example: `bash`), and will pass it the pts file name (the pts file name
  can be passed through the command line arguments for example).
- Now both `gnome-terminal` and `bash` would start reading from `/dev/pts/0`.
- When `gnome-terminal` wants to send data to `bash`, it would write this data to`/dev/pts/0`, and `bash` would read this data from `/dev/pts/0`.
- When `bash` wants to send data to `gnome-terminal`, it would write this data to`/dev/pts/0`, `and` `gnome-terminal` would read this data from `/dev/pts/0`.

This diagram shows what I just explained:

[image]

Am I correct in my understanding?

---

***Note***: of course the pts file could be a tty file if we were using virtual terminals (i.e. when we are not using a GUI), but the logic would still be the same.

Comment: See also [What are the responsibilities of each Pseudo-Terminal (PTY) component (software, master side, slave side)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117981/what-are-the-responsibilities-of-each-pseudo-terminal-pty-component-software) and [How I/O channels are implemented in Linux kernel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96694/how-i-o-channels-are-implemented-in-linux-kernel/102777#102777)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a necessary piece. Pseudo-tty devices are not symmetrical like sockets. There is a master end and a slave end. The files in `/dev/pts` represent the slave devices.

The terminal emulator creates a pseudo-tty by calling `openpty` (or `forkpty` which is `openpty` plus some bonus setup for the common case where you want to run a new process on your new tty). At a lower level this involves opening `/dev/ptmx` and doing some magic ioctls.

As a result of calling `openpty` the terminal emulator gets a pair of file descriptors, and can also get the name of the file in `/dev/pts` corresponding to the slave. The master doesn't get an individual name because there's never any need for a child process to open it by name.

Master and slave devices do act sort of like opposite ends of a socket: what you write on one end is read from the other. But because this is a tty, all the tty modes are applied to the data on the way through.

For example, if you are a terminal emulator, and you receive a keypress of the <kbd>A</kbd> key, you should write `'a'` to the master file descriptor. This is directly equivalent to sending that byte over the serial line from the terminal to the computer. It will result in `'a'` being read from the slave (by whatever program is reading it - e.g. the shell).

If you receive a keypress of the <kbd>D</kbd> key while the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is down, you should write a `4` byte (`'D' ^ 0x40`) to the master file descriptor. (Because that's what a real terminal sends on the wire.) What happens next depends on the tty mode. In raw mode, the program reading the slave tty will see a `4` byte. In cooked mode, the tty will activate the "EOF special key pressed" behavior.

In the reverse direction, there is also some processing. When some program writes `'\n'` to the slave tty, you will probably receive `"\r\n"` on the master file descriptor, because of `onlcr` post-processing.

## History section, skip if bored

Long ago, the slave devices had names like `/dev/ttyp0` and each one had a corresponding master, like `/dev/ptyp0`. They weren't dynamically created. A terminal emulator could just probe them all to find one not currently in use, and start using it. Managing ownership and permissions was a problem. `xterm` was setuid-root just so it could chown the slave.

The new scheme, called "UNIX98 ptys", handles device creation and ownership through the magic ioctls, so files only appear in `/dev/pts` when they're in use, and they are owned by the user who ran the program that created them.

Comment: So `gnome-terminal` writes data to `/dev/ptmx` and this data goes to `/dev/pts/0` and then `bash` will read this data from`/dev/pts/0`, and then `bash` writes data to `/dev/pts/0` and this data goes to `/dev/ptmx` and then `gnome-terminal` will read this data from `/dev/ptmx`? if what I'm saying is correct, then why there is only one `/dev/ptmx` file, and not something like `/dev/ptmx0`, `/dev/ptmx1`, etc. And since there is only one `/dev/ptmx` file, then how will the (kernel?) knows which data should be sent to which pts file?

Comment: @user7681202 The kernel associates a slave side to each open file descriptor on `/dev/ptmx`. Associating the slave with a file descriptor rather than with a file was a key point of the Unix98 pty scheme, so that terminal emulators wouldn't have to find a free device and set its permissions correctly.

Comment: You can think of `/dev/ptmx` as a device that generates other devices on demand - always in pairs, one having a name and the other being anonymous.